# Построить Scheme-функцию, ПОСЛЕДНИЙ (Х), которая выдает как результат последний элемент списка Х

Tags: lisp, scheme

Или я не то делаю, или оно не работает)

```
(define ln (lambda (list) (cond
                        ((eq? list () 0)
                        (#t (+ (ln (cdr list)) 1))
                        ))))
```

Comment: да, ты не то делаешь - ты считаешь элементы, а надо возвращать элемент

Comment: почему тема вопроса кардинально поменялась с подсчета количества на получение последнего?

Comment: сменили тему задачи)))

Comment: так делать не надо, лучше задавать новый вопрос, а не полностью менять содержимое старого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, есть функция `last`, но так:

```
(define (last-el l)
  (cond ((null? (cdr l)) (car l))
        (else (last-el (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: спасибо) просто в Schme нольь))

Comment: вы позанимайтесь, углубьтесь. Завидую, если у вас в ВУЗе это преподают.

Comment: мне душа не горит до этого) я себя вижу в Фрот-энд) и еще раз спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Пожалуйста, с удовольствием. Но я вас тогда удивлю: У Javascript очень много общего с Scheme, гораздо больше чем с Java, несмотря на название, C-подобный синтаксис и точки с запятыми. http://raganwald.com/2013/07/19/javascript-is-a-lisp.html 
А функциональное программирование - самый прогрессивный способ делать фронтенд. В этой связи также сейчас популярен Clojure + ClojureScript, что также Lisp.